# bounds with typyvar

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I want to make sure that the input is the same as output, I tried to use TypeVar to bound the typing but I can't get it to work...

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Any
import pandas as pd

class my_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.days = []
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, 
                 input: Union[dict, list[dict]], 
                 *args, 
                 **kwargs
                 ) -> Union[dict, list[dict]]:
        "some code"
```

what I tried:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Any
import pandas as pd

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[dict, list[dict]])

class my_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.days = []
        self.count = 0
    def __call__(self, input: T, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        "some code"
```

It's saying that it's expecting "T" and got either Dict or List but I thought since I bounded it, it will look into that Union that I defined in T? Can someone direct me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `__call__` actually return? Is that value statically typed as a `T`?

Comment: ```__call__``` can return any of those 3 that I specified as a union in T

Comment: That's what your first signature expresses. Your second one claims that it returns a `T`. If the value you're returning isn't a `T`, your code won't type check.

Comment: ```input``` in ```__call__``` and output both should be ```Union[pd.DataFrame, dict[Any, Any], list[dict[Any, Any]]]``` because they can be any of those 3

Comment: You need to use a constrained type variable. With a union bound, both the argument and the return type have the same *restrictions*, but the type bound to one is not affected by the type bound to the other. `T = TypeVar('T', pd.DataFrame, dict, list[dict])`.

Comment: @chepner I changed it to what you proposed and still running into errors. "Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[Any, Any]", expected "List[Dict[Any, Any]]") " and also vice versa... "Incompatible return value type (got "List[Dict[Any, Any]]", expected "Dict[Any, Any]]") "

Comment: What are you actually returning?

Comment: Also, there's no reason subscript either type with `Any`; `list` and `list[Any]` are equivalent.

Comment: @chepner not really, `mypy` has a flag `--disallow-any-generics` to enforce explicit usage, and it's not only to scare people. Explicit may be really better than implicit in such context to avoid accidentally forgetting type arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *constrained* type variable, not a bound type variable, in order to require that the same type be bound to `T` in both cases.

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', pd.DataFrame, dict, list[dict])

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.days = []
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, input: T, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        ...
```

With a union bound, both the argument and the return type are restricted to one of the three given types, but each use of `T` can be bound independently of the other. Further, you have no idea, statically speaking, *which* of the three will be returned. With a constrained type variable, the same type has to be bound to `T` in every occurrence within a single call to `__call__`.

---

Here's a simple example:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', int, str)

class Foo:
    def __call__(self, x: T) -> T:
        return x

x: int = Foo()(9)  # OK, 9 makes return value int
y: str = Foo()("foo")  # OK, "foo" makes return value str
z: float = Foo()(3.14)  # Fails, 3.14 not an int or str
w: str = Foo()(9)  # Fails, can' assign an int to w
```

Comment: how can I make sure that if I pass a dict, I'm going to return exactly dict as well? same with list... if I pass list as an input, I'm going to return list as well?

Comment: By using a constrained type variable as shown. `T('T', x, y, z)` is simply *different* from `T('T', bound=Union[x, y, z])`, precisely to provide the semantics of tying the argument type to the return type. It's not just two different ways of writing the same thing. (It might have been clearer if the same thing, `TypeVar`, weren't used to define two very different concepts.)